# Criando um método "verifica" em uma classe DAO

Tags: java, sql

Estou com uma dúvida na hora de criar um método que verifica se já existe um registro na minha base de dados.

Na minha base de dados tenho duas tabelas:

Tabela Usuario: (id, login, senha);
Tabela Pedidos: (id, qtd, status,id_usuario);

Gostaria de verificar o status na tabela Pedidos, sendo que a tabela Usuario possui um relacionamento com a tabela Pedidos.

A minha ideia é verificar o status de um pedido sempre que um determinado usuário tentar fazer um novo pedido, se tiver um pedido em aberto o pedido não será adicionado no banco.

Segue abaixo meu método verifica:

```
public int verificaStatus(String status, Usuario u) {
    int id = 0;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    conn = getConnection();

    try {
        stmt = conn
                .prepareStatement("SELECT pedidos.status=?, pedidos.id_usuario=?" +
                        "FROM pedidos" +
                        "INNER JOIN usuario ON pedidos.id_usuario = usuario.id" +
                        "WHERE pedidos.id_usuario = '" + u.getId() + "' ");
        stmt.setString(1, status);
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            id = resultSet.getInt("id_usuario");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    } finally {
        closeConnection(conn, (Statement) stmt, resultSet);
    }
    System.out.println("ID do Usuário: " + id);
    System.out.println("ID do u.getId(): " + u.getId());
    return id;
}
```

Segue o meu método "inserir":

```
public int inserir(Pedidos pedidos) {
 Connection conn = null;
 conn = getConnection();
 int sucesso = 0;
 Usuario u = new Usuario();
 int pedidosRealizados = verificaStatus(pedidos.getStatus()); //Nesse linha possui um erro, passei apenas o "status" como parâmetro, no método verifica é passado como parâmetro duas vaiáveis.

 if (pedidosRealizados == 0) {
     PreparedStatement stmt = null;
     try {
         stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "
                 + "pedidos (loja, status, comentario, quantidade, id_usuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

         stmt.setString(1, pedidos.getLoja());
         stmt.setString(2, pedidos.getStatus());
         stmt.setString(3, pedidos.getComentario());
         stmt.setInt(4, pedidos.getQuantidade());
         stmt.setInt(5, pedidos.getId_usuario());

         sucesso = stmt.executeUpdate();

         if (sucesso > 0) {
             System.out.println("PEDIDO REALIZADO COM SUCESSO!");
             System.out.println("Pedidos realizados: " + pedidosRealizados);
             System.out.println("Status: " + pedidos.getStatus());
         }

     } catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("ERRO AO REALIZAR O PEDIDO!");
     } finally {
         closeConnection(conn, (Statement) stmt);
     }
 } else {
     System.out.println("ERRO: EXISTE UM PEDIDO EM ABERTO");
     closeConnection(conn);
 }
 return sucesso;
}
```

Comment: Você quer verificar como? Passando um status como parâmetro? Só pode ter um pedido por vez no banco?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem, mas se você quer verificar se determinado usuário já tem um pedido em aberto você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
   public int verificaStatus(Usuario usuario) {
        int id = 0;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        conn = getConnection();
        try {
            stmt = conn
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT pedidos.status=? pedidos.id_usuario=? FROM pedidos INNER JOIN usuario ON "
                            + "pedidos.id_usuario = usuario.id" 
                            + "WHERE pedidos.id_usuario = '" + usuario.getId() + "' "
                            + "AND pedido.status = 'EM ABERTO' ");
            stmt.setString(1, status);
            resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                id = resultSet.getInt("id_usuario");
                System.out.println("ID do Usuário: " + id);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } finally {
            closeConnection(conn, (Statement) stmt, resultSet);
        }
        return id;
    }
```

Eu alterei 2 pontos em seu código. O primeiro é o parâmetro passado, estou supondo que você tenha um usuário corrente, ou seja, o usuário que está logado.

O segundo ponto são as condições adicionadas na cláusula `WHERE`:

```
"WHERE pedidos.id_usuario = '"+usuario.getId()+"' "
```

E

```
 "AND pedido.status = 'EM ABERTO' "
```

A primeira regra verifica se algum id de usuário é igual ao parâmetro passado. E a segunda se o status do pedido está aberto.

Não consegui entender muito bem sua pergunta, se não for isso é algo bem parecido, então é só adaptar seu código.

Comment: Eu esqueci de postar o método "inserir", na edição que fiz acrescentei. Minha dúvida agora é em relação ao tipo de parâmetro passado no método "verifica" eu coloquei uma string, você sugeriu um variável do tipo Usuário, só que antes de usar o "INSERT INTO" eu preciso passar uma String como parâmetro no "verificaStatus". Como fica essa questão?

Comment: É só passar junto com o usuário no parâmetro.

Comment: Dessa forma: "public int verificaStatus(Usuario usuario, String status) {}"?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Clicnet

Comment: Alterei o método verifica conforme você sugeriu, só que acabou gerando dois problemas nos métodos: 1º. O id do usuario que está no código SQL está retornando "null". 2º. Quando eu chamo o método "verifica" no método "inserir" dar um erro de tipos incompatíveis de dados pois dentro do parâmetro estou passando uma String e um tipo Usuario. Veja: "int pedidosRealizados = verificaStatus(pedidos.getStatus(),  u.getId)"; Como faço pra solucionar esse problema?

Comment: O tipo do id do usuario é o mesmo do banco?

Comment: É sim, no banco ta int(20)

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque embaixo o seu novo método

Comment: Pronto, editei. Eu testei a consulta SQL do método verifica atribuindo um id no "u.getId" e deu certo retornou todos os status de um usuário específico. Ou seja a consulta SQL tá ok.